# How to specify ngx-formly field formatter when field config is coming from service

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

In the application that I am working on. We are getting the fields config as part of service json response.

For some input fields we need to have a specific formatter.
Example : For few input fields we need to turn the entered input value to uppercase. All the backend can send is a flag for fields whose value should be formatted

Example: templateOptions : {
tranformToUpperCase : true
}

Is there a better way to do such transform/formatting on input text.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your fields config is some like

```
fields=[{name:'name',label:'Name'},{name:'surname',label:'Surname'}]
```

just add another property 'style', e.g.

```
fields=[{name:'name',label:'Name',style:{'text-transform':'uppercase'}},
        {name:'surname',label:'Surname',style:{'text-transform':'uppercase'}}]
```

Just use [ngStyle]

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    {{field.label}}
    <input [ngStyle]="field.style" [formControlName]="field.name">
  </div>
</form>
```

NOTE: I suppose you has some similar to

```
form=this.getEmptyForm();

getEmpyForm()
{ 
   const form=new FormGroup({});
   this.fields.forEach(x=>{
      form.addControl(x.name)
   })
   return form;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is in context of using form with https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly